# Declaring the module of a defproc or deform (function/macro documentation) when split across multiple files

Tags: documentation, racket, scribble

In scribble, I can use [`defproc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-forms.html?q=defproc#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._defproc%29%29) and [`defform`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-forms.html?q=defform#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._defform%29%29) to define the documentation for a function or macro. And then scribble uses the nearest [`defform`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-modules.html?q=defmodule#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._defmodule%29%29) in the file to determine what module the function/macro is defined in.

However, sometimes it sometimes makes sense to have the documentation for the same module split up across multiple scribble files.

(Say if you want the documentation for a `init` function to be in `repl.scrbl`, and you wan the documentation for `find` in `api.scrbl`. But both of them are defined in the same module, say `repl.rkt`.)

However, Scribble complains when there are multiple substantiations of the same `defmodule` in the docs:

```
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(index-entry (mod-path "zordoz")); values: (list '("zordoz") (list (link-element (style "RktModLink" (list 'tt-chars #0=(list (css-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.css")) (tex-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.tex"))))) (cached-element (style "RktSym" (list 'tt-chars #0#)) "zordoz... (list '("zordoz") (list (link-element (style "RktModLink" (list 'tt-chars #0=(list (css-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.css")) (tex-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.tex"))))) (cached-element (style "RktSym" (list 'tt-chars #0#)) "zordoz...
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(mod-path "zordoz"); values: '#(("REPL") (mod-path "zordoz") (2) (doc #"main" #"index.html") #f) '#(("API") (mod-path "zordoz") (3) (doc #"main" #"index.html") #f)
raco setup: rendering: <pkgs>/zordoz/scribblings/main.scrbl
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(index-entry (mod-path "zordoz")); values: (list '("zordoz") (list (link-element (style "RktModLink" (list 'tt-chars #0=(list (css-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.css")) (tex-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.tex"))))) (cached-element (style "RktSym" (list 'tt-chars #0#)) "zordoz... (list '("zordoz") (list (link-element (style "RktModLink" (list 'tt-chars #0=(list (css-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.css")) (tex-addition '(collects #"scribble" #"racket.tex"))))) (cached-element (style "RktSym" (list 'tt-chars #0#)) "zordoz...
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(mod-path "zordoz"); values: '#(("REPL") (mod-path "zordoz") (2) (doc #"main" #"index.html") #f) '#(("API") (mod-path "zordoz") (3) (doc #"main" #"index.html") #f)
```

So, is there any way I can document both functions across multiple scribble files, even though they are defined in the same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of these files are included as subsections of another file, say `main.rkt`, you can put the `defproc` in that file and the two other files will use it as the module for `defproc` and `defform`.

For example:

```
#lang scribble/manual

@title{Zordoz}

@defmodule[zordoz]
@include-section[repl.scrbl]
@include-section[api.scrbl]
```